# What is the opposite of a Pyrrhic Victory called?

Tags: word-usage

What is a term for something that is the opposite of a Pyrrhic Victory?

As an example, Mark Twain gave a lecture in New York at Cooper's Union which lost money (they "papered the house" out of fear of having an empty hall), even though the place was full "to the rafters" (SRO).

He lost money in the short term (or the impresario, Frank Fuller, did, anyway), but reviews were good and it paved the way for more engagements which did make money. IOW, it was a "good investment" / "it takes money to make money" situation.

Is there a phrase that describes this sort of thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Pyrrhic defeat?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240011/a-pyrrhic-defeat)

Comment: What are you trying to negate? If I pick the opposite of *both* words, I end up with *a* ***trivial defeat***.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply called a *victory*.  A writer could emphasize the absence of the qualifier *Pyrrhic* by pointing out that it's an *unqualified victory*.